How do I amend my IF AND statement to correctly show payments made or not?
I've been trying to set up a formula to show if someone has paid their membership fees. They can either pay yearly or monthly. The yearly formula seems to be working but the monthly formula seems to not work. Basically, I want it to show - if the month referenced is either the current month or a later month - if the person named for that row has paid for that month. If possible, I also want to show if someone has said they've paid but the payment isn't showing in the bank.
This is the 'Income - Membership fees' sheet referenced in the formula.

And this is the main sheet and the formula:
=IF(AND('Income - Membership fees'!$C:$C = $A2, E$1 < TODAY(),'Income - Membership fees'!$E:$E = E$1, $C2 = "Monthly",'Income - Membership fees'!$G:$G = "Yes"),"PAID", IF(AND('Income - Membership fees'!$C:$C = $A2, E$1 < TODAY(),'Income - Membership fees'!$E:$E = E$1, $C2 = "Monthly",'Income - Membership fees'!$G:$G <> "Yes"),"NOT IN BANK", IF(OR(E$1 > TODAY(),$C2 <> "Monthly"),"","NOT PAID")))


I've tried using vlookup, and * instead of AND. I've also tried looking into byrow, lambda, and match but I don't know if they're the right thing for me to use.

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

If you do what @z.. recommends, please make sure the question doesn’t rely on this “question sheet” to be answerable. Questions here must stand alone without external requirements.

I've created the sample sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XGSY2xZV6pKbfFK8uP5IYKWIwidMPF-aPVu60sXCthw/edit?usp=sharing

Hi all, thank you for your tips and advice - it's my first time posting so it's helpful to have the information. I've hopefully now edited my post to be within guidance.

use:
=INDEX(LET(a, A2:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))),    b, OFFSET(a,,1), 
           d, D1:INDEX(1:1,,MAX(COLUMN(1:1)*(1:1<>""))), c, 'Income - Membership fees'!C:C, 
 IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(a&b&"Yes"&d, {c&OFFSET(c,,1)&OFFSET(c,,4)&OFFSET(c,,2)}, 1,))<>"","PAID", 
 IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(a&b&"No"&d,  {c&OFFSET(c,,1)&OFFSET(c,,4)&OFFSET(c,,2)}, 1,))<>"","NOT IN BANK", 
 IF((b<>"Monthly")+(d>TODAY()),,"NOT PAID")))))



Hi, thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately it seems to be showing me the same results as previously, but I'm not sure why. For example, with the values set as they currently are on the 'Income - Membership fees' tab, it should be showing PAID for April 24, March 24 and February 24 because (for Sophie B paying monthly) the dates are in the past, the values are present in the  'Income - Membership fees' tab, and the money is set as showing in the bank
